# jq - Discrepancy in newline treatment between bash and zsh and zsh-subshell

Tags: jq, zsh

I'm trying to [format a string as JSON](https://gist.github.com/jakub-g/b2ef123f8b754bc5c63bc854e7019987) using `jq` and I noticed differing behaviors on bash vs zsh; specifically when zsh runs `jq` directly, the outcome is different than when it runs it in subshell: `\n` input gets output as `\\n` in first case, vs as`\n` in the latter.

I'm puzzled and not sure what's going on there:

- Is this a known zsh behavior?
- Is this a `jq` bug?
- Or does it work as designed and I'm missing something?

BTW: [Use newline with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391180/use-newline-with-jq) suggests to use `printf %b` to obtain `\n` instead of `\\n`, which works for bash,. but discrepancy in `zsh` between the modes is still there.

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6

# ---
# Using \n directly

bash-3.2$        jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test 'A\nB' '{test: $test}'
{"test":"A\\nB"}
bash-3.2$  OUT=$(jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test 'A\nB' '{test: $test}'); echo $OUT
{"test":"A\\nB"}


zsh-5.8.1>       jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test 'A\nB' '{test: $test}'
{"test":"A\\nB"}
zsh-5.8.1> OUT=$(jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test 'A\nB' '{test: $test}'); echo $OUT
{"test":"A\nB"}

# -----
# Using `printf %b` to convert `\n` to real newline

bash-3.2$        jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test "$(printf %b 'A\nB')" '{test: $test}'
{"test":"A\nB"}
bash-3.2$  OUT=$(jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test "$(printf %b 'A\nB')" '{test: $test}'); echo $OUT
{"test":"A\nB"}


zsh-5.8.1>       jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test "$(printf %b 'A\nB')" '{test: $test}'
{"test":"A\nB"}
zsh-5.8.1> OUT=$(jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test "$(printf %b 'A\nB')" '{test: $test}'); echo $OUT
{"test":"A
B"}
```

Comment: `echo` is perhaps the only place I'm aware of where zsh is _more_ compliant with the POSIX specification on default settings than bash is. (Treating backslash-escape expansion as always-on is explicitly permitted; treating it as always-off is also permitted; turning it on only when `-e` is present is not okay, as `-n` is the only thing `echo` is allowed to treat as a flag).

Comment: (because POSIX specifies that `echo`'s output becomes unspecified when any backslash is present in input, one can argue that this makes `echo -e`'s behavior permissible in bash... but I'd argue that this makes it permissible _only when there's actually a backslash somewhere in the string_, but bash's `echo` consumes `-e` as an option even when no backslashes are present in later arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` behavior is the same between both shells, as are all the shell expansions related to your `jq` invocation -- but default `echo` behavior differs.

You can avoid this by switching from `echo` to `printf`.

```
% OUT=$(jq --null-input --compact-output --raw-output --monochrome-output --arg test "$(printf %b 'A\nB')" '{test: $test}')
% printf '%s\n' "$OUT"
{"test":"A\nB"}
```

Comment: TIL! Thanks! From my quick test it seems that zsh `echo` works like bash `echo -e` when it comes to `\n` printing.

Comment: `echo` is a mess. For a fun read, see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html -- the very standards document defining `echo` recommends using `printf` instead.